# Silverlight loses authentication on Page Refresh

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mvvm

I am building a SL4 application that uses the standard authentication built into the business template. The user logs in and is then redirected to a new page. If the user then refreshes that page, the WebContext.Current.User returns null. Why does this happen? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you are handling your authentication context inside the Silverlight application, and when the page is refreshed, a new Silverlight application is instantiated and therefore a new authentication context is created, on which the user has not provided credentials yet. In order to prevent this it is necessary for you to move the authentication context to an upper layer, at the browser and authenticate using a server side technology like ASP.NET and have Silverlight leverage that authentication context instead of handling its own context.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Are you then saying that the authentication provided in the stock standard Silverlight Biz Application template can never work? I am not finding too much on google regarding page refreshes in Silverlight which makes me think there isnt a problem. Having said that, I have built a project that works great UNLESS pages of refreshed - the data loads according to parameters in global variables and these variables get emptied on page refreshes so its more that just authentication thats affected.